# How to have flexible buttons allign in android?

Tags: android, button, layout, alignment

Hi question maybe difficult to understand but I will try my best.
     First of all this is the code

```
    <Linear
android:id="@+id/interestLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/layout_roots"

android:background="#e0e0e0">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dancing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ruhesi_buttondesigns"
    android:onClick="toggling"
    android:text="@string/dancing"
    android:textColor="#FF4444" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cooking"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dancing"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dancing"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dancing"
    android:background="@drawable/ruhesi_buttondesigns"
    android:onClick="toggling"
    android:text="@string/cooking"
    android:textColor="#FF4444" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/painting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cooking"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cooking"
    android:background="@drawable/ruhesi_buttondesigns"
    android:onClick="toggling"
    android:text="@string/painting"

    android:textColor="#FF4444" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/playing_instruments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/painting"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/painting"
    android:background="@drawable/ruhesi_buttondesigns"
    android:onClick="toggling"
    android:text="@string/playing_instruments"
    android:textColor="#FF4444" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pets"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playing_instruments"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/playing_instruments"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ruhesi_buttondesigns"
    android:onClick="toggling"
    android:text="@string/playing_instruments"
    android:textColor="#FF4444" />
    </Linear>
```

So this generates me this picture:
[Located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O2I1.jpg)

So as we all now each device has a different screen size so in big device probably all these buttons will be in one line alligned but in smaller screen I want that buttons to be alligned (for example last button not visible it should go to below). So in one row there can be 3 buttons on the second row there can be 2 buttons depends on the text of the button and next row maybe again 3 buttons. How we can give this flexibility ?

Comment: Have different layouts for the different screens?

Comment: I think there must be better solution it is like extra work to do. maintaining each layout for just one flexibility. I will check that answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the Android's stock layouts provide this behavior, but there's multiple libraries to achieve this, such as the following: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Their github page has instructions on how to use it, on top of that you can implement your own layout manager, but its a little more complicated.

If you google FlowLayout Android you'll find more information.

If you don't need such flexibility, you can also provide different layouts for different screen sizes, you can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I will check it now Thank you.

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you again.
Here is a better library for it:
https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout